# Endless non-scrolling using whileElement().scroll() on ScrollView components

Tags: detox

I can't quite nail it down to a specific version, but somewhere after 9.0 and persisting until 10.0.7, when attempting to use the `waitFor(element).toBeVisible().whileElement(element).scroll()` method, Detox successfully finds the scrollable content, but is starting the scroll from what appears to be underneath our footer bar.

I can see the action indicator on the simulator grabbing and scrolling, but the screen doesn't scroll at all. Is there a way to specify an offset to start the scroll action at?

[.gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNvbM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a startPositionX and startPositionY, as described here:

https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#scrollpixels-direction-startpositionxnan-startpositionynan

---

## scroll(pixels, direction, startPositionX=NaN, startPositionY=NaN)

Scrolls a given amount of pixels in the provided direction, starting from the provided start positions.

*pixels* - independent device pixels

*direction* - left/right/up/down

*startPositionX* - the X starting scroll position, in percentage; valid input: [0.0, 1.0], NaN; default: NaN—choose the best value automatically

*startPositionY* - the Y starting scroll position, in percentage; valid input: [0.0, 1.0], NaN; default: NaN—choose the best value automatically

```js
await element(by.id('scrollView')).scroll(100, 'down', NaN, 0.85);
await element(by.id('scrollView')).scroll(100, 'up');
```